# How to use DraggableScrollableController in DraggableScrollableSheet?

Tags: flutter

I want to use the controller here to get the size. But every time I use it, it says it is to be attached. How to attach it?

Comment: can you include your-code snippet that you;ve tried so far

Answer (score 0):

you can use modal bottom sheet that returns a `DraggableScrollableSheet` and in the builder function return a scrollable widget takes the callback controller returned from the `builder` function. use `initialChildSize` to indicate the initial height and `minChildSize` `maxChildSize` to handle the the drag height.

```
showModalBottomSheet(
   backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
   enableDrag: true,
   context: context,
     builder: (_){
       return DraggableScrollableSheet(
         initialChildSize: 0.9,
         minChildSize: 0.2,
         maxChildSize: 1,
         builder: (BuildContext context, ScrollController scrollController) {
            return Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16,),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                  color: backGround,
                ),
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
                controller: scrollController,
                 child: Column(
                    children: [
                       //your widgets here
                    ],
                   ),
                 ),
               );
             },
           );
         },
      );
```